# Problem with output from exec('7za.exe e -so ...')

Tags: php, exec

It feels like some of the data is being cut off somewhere:

```
@exec('7za.exe" e -so "archive.zip" "img.jpg"', $out);
```

$out - is a array of bin data
$data = implode( "" , $out );
imagecreatefromstring($data); // not working

if added "\r\n" to implode():
$data = implode( "\r\n" , $out );
imagecreatefromstring($data); // creates a distorted image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtN96.jpg)

File is correct, and reading with other functions is normal, but i'm need to use a local 7za.exe, not built-in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec()` is only meant for programs that output text. Here you need to get binary content, so you should use [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/passthru) instead.

To capture the result, you will need to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
passthru('7za.exe ...');
$data = ob_get_clean();
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```